# Concat fields using apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have following function. So I would like to take 2 fields and concatenate them but when my pipeline finishes it doesn´t work

the pipeline finishes as correct but when I see in bigquery the fields have not been concatenated

It will be great if u can help me.

it´s the code used in the function:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from ..tools import ProcessLogger

_logger = ProcessLogger()


class ConcatFieldsFn(beam.DoFn):
    """Concatena los valores de los campos especificados en una pCollection por un valor especificado"""

    def __init__(self, process: str, data_name: str, parameters: dict):
        # Configuracion del logger
        self.logger_data_name = data_name
        self.logger_process = process
        self.logger_subprocess = "Concatenar valores"
        _logger.data_name = self.logger_data_name
        _logger.process = self.logger_process
        _logger.subprocess = self.logger_subprocess

        # Parametros del proceso
        self._fields = [field.get("name") for field in parameters.get("fields", None)]


        _logger.info(
            f"Se aplica regla: {_logger.subprocess} con los parametros: {parameters}"
        )

    def process(self, element):
        # Configuracion del logger
        _logger.data_name = self.logger_data_name
        _logger.process = self.logger_process
        _logger.subprocess = self.logger_subprocess

        for field in self._fields:
            if element[field] != None:
                try:
                    element[field] = "|".join(element[field])
                except Exception as ex:
                    _logger.error(
                        f"No se pueden eliminar las letras de los campos seleccionados: {ex}"
                    )
        return [element]
```

Comment: Are you sure ````element[field]```` is not None ?

Comment: Could you try logging the value returned from the DoFn ([element]) ? If you are using Dataflow Runner logs will be available in the Cloud Console. See here for more info - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging